# unity app crashes, when signing in with google, using firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I am trying to add a 'sign in with google' option to my app, using firebase. However when I click the button which calls the sign in script on my android device, the app crashes and closes completely.

I cannot run this script in the editor. so is there another way of finding out what the error is?

I am using the script found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/qss2wk4v52d48j4/GoogleSignInDemo.cs?dl=0
and have taken the web client id from my firebase project, and enabled google sign in.

I have also added the sha1 fingerprint to my firebase project and have copied the google-services.json file to my unity project.
I am using Unity 2020.1.6f1
My firebase packages are version 7.0.1
and the google sign in plugin 1.0.4

Would appreciate all help on fixing this issue and getting the sign in with google option to work.

I have found that my code breaks here:

```
 GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnAuthenticationFinished);
```

This is the OnAuthenticationFinished method:

```
internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task){}
```

I have left it empty to make sure the problem isn't inside the method

Comment: It'll be had to debug without some log, so I'll give you a few suggestions. 1) you can monitor your app with logcat, if this isn't something you're familiar with I tend to recommend this Unity plugin: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html

2) you can attach a managed debugger. If you use either Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio on Windows you can click attach -- I've had bad luck with Rider and VSCode.

3) just start taking out code until the crash doesn't happen and let me know where it breaks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify title of question, include [example] of your code, . See [ask]

Comment: Patrick Martin thank you for the reply. I have taken out some code, like you suggested to find out where it breaks and edited the question accordingly. Hopefully it helps to understand the problem. I will also try working with logcat and update

Answer (score 1):

I am beginer C# and Unity.
I belive OnAuthenticationFinished run in background thread (Difference with Unity Main thread).
If you update UI or print log in OnAuthenticationFinished() cause the crash.

And I fix this issue by save value in OnAuthenticationFinished() to variable. And use them in Update()

```
private string idToken;
private bool errorMessage;

void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
{
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
   err = true;
   return;
  }
  idToken = task.Result.IdToken;
    
}


private void Update()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(idToken))
    {
        // Handle login successfully
        idToken = null;
        return;
    }

    if (err)
    {
        // Show err
      err = false;
    }
}
```

Or you can use Corrountine() like Digvijaysinh Gohil.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I see your problem. `OnAuthenticationFinished` is likely firing in the background, and `AddToInformation` is mutating something in the `UnityEngine` (namely updating `infoText.text`).

If you replace `ContinueWith` with [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension), it may just work. I would recommend doing this to all instances of `ContinueWith` in your code for now. It may be slightly less efficient (you're doing work on your game thread), but it's also much safer in Unity. Otherwise I would need to see a log to figure out what the problem is. See [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and post. However replacing those commands did not work. I will work with logcat like you suggested and upload the log

Comment: @YaronBarlevy did you find anything? I am struggling a lot with `ContinueWith`/`ContinueWithOnMainThread`. I feel like Unity can't handle it if you use it more than a couple of times. My app completely relies on Firebase. But I am in a no-go state as Unity is almost always crashing now :(

Comment: It would be awesome if you could file any performance regressions with ContinueWithOnMainThread here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues (you'd need to demonstrate it with one of the quickstarts to get folks to look at it, but it would be good to track!). Otherwise, I did a writeup of multithreading strategies here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html (and a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzFDXvZxKM ) which has other things you can try. Maybe async/await or just Coroutines. It would require more re-architecting though.

Comment: I make a lot of content for Firebase + Unity stuff, so I really want to know if you do run into issues in the wild and if something works better!

Comment: I have not been able to fix the problem. replacing 'ContinueWith' to 'continueWithOnMainThread' did not work. I am fairly new to c# and especially coroutines. and have no idea how to proceed.                                                                      Currently i am simply relying on sign in with email and password options for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue and `ContinueWithOnMain` was not working for me either so I basically defined coroutines and made them wait for the end of frame before performing other instructions

here is the code I did

```
FirebaseAuthHandler.instance.GetAuth().SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(authTask =>
                {
                    if (authTask.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        signInCompleted.SetCanceled();
                        Debug.Log("Task canceled");
                    }
                    else if (authTask.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        signInCompleted.SetException(authTask.Exception);
                        StartCoroutine(OnFailure(authTask.Exception));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        signInCompleted.SetResult(authTask.Result);                            
                        StartCoroutine(OnSuccess(authTask.Result));
                    }
                });
```

and the coroutines are as follow

```
    private IEnumerator OnSuccess(FirebaseUser authTaskResult)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Debug.Log("OnSuccess");
        // Do stuff here
    }

    private IEnumerator OnFailure(AggregateException authTaskException)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        // Do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an r8/proguard issue. I've added these lines to the proguard rules and it stopped crashing:

```
-keep class com.google.googlesignin.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.** { *; }
```

Comment: Hi @threedollarbill, can you please show me a screenshot, I tried this but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was using same script and had same issue. The reason behind this problem is "`AddToInformation()`" is mutating something in unity engine as Patrick said.
The simplest solution for this is to comment/remove "`AddToInformation()`" function from the script. Its just for debug purposes and wont affect functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i had a problem with the built APK crashing at the end. the problem was with the dependence and i solved it with changing the setting on Assets>external  dependency manger > android > setting. and turning off Auto resolution. then deleting the .aar files. after that i resolved the dependencies. that solved my problem i hope that helps . for more information

[Firebase for Unity sample app crashes with: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152445/firebase-for-unity-sample-app-crashes-with-could-not-find-class-com-google-and)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance` in a line of code before signing in, otherwise, it would crash every time.

```
_ = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential( [...] );
```